# Solve Transport Equation using Method of Characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve $$u_t+\frac{1}{t^2+1}u_x=0  ; u(0,x)=u_0(x)$$
using the method of characteristics. I know that the slopes of the chacteristics is $$\frac{dx}{dt}=t^2+1$$ so integrating gives $x = \frac{t^3}{3}+t+c$. Does that mean the solution is $$u(t,x)=f(x-(\frac{t^3}{3}+t))$$

Comment: It does not satisfy the pde though...

Comment: Almost right. The characteristics satisfy $$\frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{1}{t^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_t+\frac{1}{t^2+1}u_x=0  $$
The system of characteristic differential equations is :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\frac{1}{t^2+1}}=\frac{du}{0}$$
Necessarily $du=0\quad\to\quad$ First characteristic equation : $u=c_1$

From $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\frac{1}{t^2+1}}\quad\to\quad x=\int\frac{dt}{t^2+1}\quad\to\quad$ Second characteristic equation : $x-\tan^{-1}t=c_2$

General solution on form of implicite equation : $\Phi(u,x-\tan^{-1}t)=0$ where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables. The equivalent explicite form is :
$$u=F(x-\tan^{-1}t)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

With the initial condition : $ u(0,x)=u_0(x)=F(x-\tan^{-1}0)=F(x) \quad\to\quad F(X)=u_0(X)$

$X=x-\tan^{-1}t\quad\to\quad u(x,t)=u_0(x-\tan^{-1}t)$