# Method of Characteristics: Characteristic Curve Question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, characteristics

I was browsing through some questions on Method of Characteristics and came across a couple solutions involving characteristic curves:
1. [Solve Transport Equation using Method of Characteristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947302/solve-transport-equation-using-method-of-characteristics)
2. [Solve the PDE by method of characteristics.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566550/solve-the-pde-by-method-of-characteristics)

This method involving the "system of characteristic differential equations" is different to the approach I was taught, and it makes a lot more sense.

The method we were told involves writing out a differential for each segment of the PDE, solving it, and applying boundary and/or initial conditions when necessary. It becomes messy and there are terms popping up, I don't really understand it, despite attempting to go through numerous example questions. I decided to study the 2 questions above.

My problem is with the second one, I just cannot understand it.

> First family of characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{dx}{x^2} \quad\to\quad \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{x}=c_1$

My workout led to a different solution:

> $$dx=\frac{x^2}{t^2}dt$$ 
>   $$x=\int\frac{x^2}{t^2}dt$$

This allows me to divide both sides by $x^2$. Integrating $t^{-2}$ gives $-t^{-1}+C_1$. My answer is:

> $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{t}=C_1$$

Then comes the second bit:

> Second family of characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{dx}{x^2}= \frac{\frac1tdt+\frac1xdx}{\frac1tt^2+\frac1xx^2} = \frac{\frac1tdt+\frac1xdx}{t+x}=\frac{du}{(t+x)u}$
>   $\frac1tdt+\frac1xdx=\frac{du}{u} \quad\to\quad \frac{u}{tx}=c_2$

Which I do not understand at all.

I decided to do some algebra, and it seems that the pile comes from this:
$$\frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dt}{t}=0$$
Then dividing both sides by $(x+t)$, combining the two fractions, and subsequently equating it with $\frac{du}{(t+x)u}$.

I then tried to solve the equation:

> $$\frac{tdx+xdt}{tx(x+t)}=\frac{du}{(t+x)u}$$

Which gave me some natural logarithmic. 
I multiplied both sides by $t+x$, and then integrated both sides:

> $$\frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{du}{u}$$
>   $$log(x)+log(t)-log(u)=C_2$$
>   Edit: I think this is wrong. I cannot integrate the equation with regards to 3 different differentials, right?

Raising this mess as the power of $e$ gets rid of the logs.
And, I am stuck. This looks completely different to the answer, and clearly wrong.

The first issue was likely a typo, since the negative sign was not carried through the calculations.

Any help regarding to the question is greatly appreciated. I tried looking online for material regarding to this approach and did not find anything useful. All the materials I can find does not involve "system of characteristic differential equations" but rather goes straight to various differentials. I think the second step has something to do with separation of variables.

Thanks!

Comment: I found this article: http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/m3414_1.pdf I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First family: “This allows me to divide both sides by $x^2$.” No, you can't. The variables $x$ and $t$ are not independent, so you can't take $x^2$ outside of the $t$ integral.

What you have is
$$dt/t^2= dx/x^2 \iff d(-1/t)=d(-1/x) \iff d(1/t-1/x)=0 \iff 1/t-1/x=c_1.$$

Second family: If $A=B$, then $(tA+xB)/(t+x)=(tA+xA)/(t+x)=A(t+x)/(t+x)=A$ (which also equals $B$). That is,
$$
A=B 
\quad\implies\quad
A = B = \frac{tA+xB}{t+x}
.
$$
The computation starts out by applying this identity with $A=dt/t^2$ and $B=dx/x^2$.

And then you get
$$
dt/t + dx/x = du/u
\iff
d \ln|t| + d \ln|x| = d \ln|u|
\iff
d \ln|\tfrac{u}{xt}|=0
\iff
\tfrac{u}{xt}=c_2
.
$$
(If the logarithm of the absolute value of something is constant, then that something itself is constant too.)

Comment: Thanks! I realised the division problem after attempting another problem, doing the same thing, and it led to nonsense. I'll try to comprehend the second family.

Comment: Alright, the relation $A=B=\frac{tA+xB}{t+x}$ is essentially lowering the order two relationship to order one, right? Where does the term $t+x$ go though? There seems to be many clever tricks of this sort, our teacher simply told us to "remember them" is there a good paper online that I may go through to get a hold of it? Thanks for the help so far, greatly appreciated!

Comment: You multiply by $t+x$ on both sides. And yes, that $(tA+xB)/(t+x)$ thing was indeed clever; I don't know if I would have come up with that... You'll have to ask the original answerer where that came from!